# Java Swing, iterate through text Area

Tags: java, string, swing, indexof

I want to find the word occurrence in text area, so each time I press `button`  it will search for next occurrence of specified word, just like Ctrl+F does. Does anyone know how can I do that?
This is the code that finds only 1st occurrence of given word.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if (button == arg0.getSource()) {
        int index = textArea.getText().indexOf(find.getText());
        int len = find.getText().length();
        Highlighter.HighlightPainter highlight = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.BLACK);
        try {
            textArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(index, index + len, highlight);
        } 
        catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`textArea` is the text area where I have words, and `find` is the text field where I search for a specific word in `textArea`.

Comment: As stated in the docs, you can start looking from an index. So you will need a way to determine what was the last index you searched for, and add one http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)

Comment: @Michael Pickett Ok, I will try to do this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save index of previous occurance as field and use two argument indexOf method, which takes String and startIndex as arguments.

ETA: `public int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`